# Two or more prepositional phrases in one clause

Tags: standard-german

How often do you see two or more prepositional phrases in one clause?

For example, I was reading the LA Times and was curious how a sentence would translate in German. Google translated it like this:

> “Premierministerin Theresa May hat wiederholt versprochen, das Land aus seiner jahrzehntelangen Mitgliedschaft im 28-köpfigen Block in eine glänzende, prosperierende Zukunft zu führen.”

This is unusual, right?

Comment: Not at all. Google Translate did it right.

Comment: It is not unusual per se, but this sentence, in that form, would not make its way into a (good) newspaper. It is too twisted. The reader, even an intelligent one, gets lost while reading. Not least because of the famous German postposition of the verb. So, for a newspaper, this sentence needs re-grouping. Moreover, *28-köpfiger Block* (for the EU, as we can suppose) is a nonsense metaphor; nobody uses this, and thus a newspaper wouldn't. *Blöcke* do not have heads in German.

Comment: Moreover, *glänzend und prosperierend* is overdone. Delete any one of the adverbs, and the sentence keeps totally its meaning. So, one is redundant and would be edited out.

Comment: Since there is only a limited number or *non*-adverbial complements (subject, object etc.) for any given construction, *any* sentence of a certain length is practically forced to have multiple adverbials (prepositions, adverbs, etc.) if it wants to give additional information.

Comment: In a newspaper the sentence may be unusual, but in scientific or literary writing it would not be unusual at all.

Answer (score 3):

This is not at all unusual.

> Der ICE 583 bringt Sie ohne Umsteigen auf schnellstem Weg von Hamburg über Hannover, Würzburg, Nürnberg nach München.